# Regexplace for removing decimals

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regex-negation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I get text values, which I translate to numbers by using the `Regexplace` function.
This is the formula I'm using:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE((Q197:Q); "[^\d\.]+";)*1)
```

PROBLEM: The values in Q are sometimes numbers (formatted as strings, unfortunately, which is why I use this formula) that include two decimal digits. Some other values don't.
In case the values in Q include decimal values I would like to cut them off.

QUESTION: How can I cut off decimal digits when using the `REGEXREPLACE` formula, even though only some input values contain decimal digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDDOWN(REGEXREPLACE(Q197:Q; "[^\d\.]+"; )*1; 0))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDDOWN(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TO_TEXT(Q1:Q); "."; ","); "[^\d\.|,]+"; ); 0)*1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This does unfortunately not work.
Test data could be
Q1=473
Q2=473,99
Both should result in 473.

Comment: I don't really know what that means (google didn't help either). I would like to show numbers without decimals. The decimals can just be cut off.

Comment: Okay, so this does not work for numbers like this: 1,234.56. So basically numbers in their thousands with two decimal numbers. Is there a way to modify this formula for this case?

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TO_TEXT(Q1:Q); "."; ","); "[^\d\.|,]+"; ); 0); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(Q1:Q; ","; ""); "(.*)\."))*1)` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGLMi.png

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. 1,343.25 results in 1.

Comment: Yes of course! I have isolated the relevant column in A. And used this formula in B. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yIu0cMeDgbVhPwYM5bqhRUU8BUYzhKCGaPCGJFm8qoU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try if this works for you: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A:A; "."; ); "\d+")*1))` (column C in your sheet)